# Cannot Work with mxmlGetText and mxmlGetElemet in mxml

Tags: c, gcc, mxml

```
#include <mxml.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fp;

    mxml_node_t *tree;
    mxml_node_t *node  = NULL;

    fp = fopen("1.xml", "r");

    tree = mxmlLoadFile(NULL, fp, MXML_OPAQUE_CALLBACK);

    node = tree;

    fprintf(stderr, "Element::%s\n", mxmlGetElement(node));
    fprintf(stderr, "Value::%s\n", mxmlGetText(node, 0));
}
```

Above is My Code snippet ... Error is

```
xmlparsing.c: In function ‘main’:
xmlparsing.c:20:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
xmlparsing.c:21:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
/tmp/ccAYsMOB.o: In function `main':
xmlparsing.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `mxmlGetElement'
xmlparsing.c:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `mxmlGetText'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Already included the mxml.h than why undefined reference?  I searched about this functions on the Internet, and links show me that it's in mxml.h header file.

Comment: How did you invoke your compiler? Did you pass the linker the path for the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with your Linker, see that last message:

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

You need to inform the `gcc` (which is a call to a compiler and linker about the include path and the library path. 
The include path is where `mxml.h` is found, this will be done with:

```
-I<path/to/include/mxml.h>
```

The library path is given with:

```
-L<path/to/shared/libmxml.a>
```

So in total you should have:

```
gcc yourfile.c -I <path/to/include/mxml.h> -L <path/to/shared/libmxml.a>
```

You can include other paths as needed.